# Is saying your voice is not audible correct?

Tags: american-english

Is this sentence correct?

> **Your voice is not audible**

or

> **you are not audible**

or are both of them are correct?

Comment: Both are correct. One or other might be preferable in certain contexts. **You are not audible from the back of the hall.** And:  **Because of your throat infection, your voice is not audible at present.**

Comment: So if I am talking to someone on zoom, and I am not able to hear the person's voice properly, will saying `your voice is not audible` is proper in this context?

Comment: No. Not only is the wording far too formal for a zoom call, you're not hitting the reason why they're not audible. Usually people ask if the person is on mute, or ask them to speak up.

Comment: @Daniel you can simply say "I can't hear you"

Comment: I agree with the other comments.  Typical phrases you hear on Zoom are: "You're muted/on mute" or "I can't hear you.  (Maybe your audio/mic/microphone isn't working, or maybe there's something wrong with my settings."

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable, though "Your voice is not audible" is probably more grammatically correct.  Strictly speaking, it is a sound that is audible rather than a person, but generally people will imply the sound by specifying the thing creating the sound, as in this case where the sound in question being your voice is implicit.

I suppose you could make sounds in other ways, but  in that case you would specify it - such as "The duchess ['s voice] was audible around the room" vs. "The duchess' *breaking wind* was audible around the room"

You wouldn't say "His book is not audible" as a book generally doesn't make a specific sound, but you could say "The cat was audible" as cats are known to make a certain sound.